# What does the expression "last leg of the trip" mean?

Tags: expressions

> *That was why the agents had just left a card saying I should pay the
> Seattle Police a call. The cops didn’t think it was worth hanging
> around just to catch some college student who’d figured out how to
> make free cell phone calls.*
>
> *Under different circumstances, I might have felt relieved.*
>
> *I left Seattle on a Greyhound bus headed for Tacoma, where I would
> board a train for Portland, and then fly the **last leg of the trip** to
> Los Angeles.*
>
> *En route, I called Ron Austin and told him I had been raided. Turned
> out my talking to Ron wasn’t such a great idea: like Petersen, he had
> become a snitch in the hope of getting a reduced sentence.*

*Observation: the writing above belongs to the **Ghost in the Wires: May Adventures as the World's Most Wanted Hacker** book written by authors Kevin Mitnick, Steve Wozniak and Wiliam L. Simon.*

What does mean the expression **"last leg of the trip"** on the writing above?

Comment: I found the answer. The expression on the question means the last stop of a trip. [Check this answer for understading that better.](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/126586/usage-of-last-leg)

Comment: You should go ahead and post an answer to the question.

Comment: This could be answered with a dictionary and is therefore off-topic. https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/leg

Answer (score 0):

The answer I've found on own SE community was that the expression ***"last leg of the trip"*** on the question means the last stop of a trip.

References:

1. [Usage of last
   leg](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/126586/usage-of-last-leg)
2. [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/leg)

Comment: I don't understand it to mean the last stop, but the journey between the last two stops.

Comment: @ColinFine That is my understanding, too, and accords with an example at the definition that Astralbee found: "The last leg of the race was Paris to London."